# Proving existence of an infinite path in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Consider the following inductive predicate:

```
inductive terminating where
 "(⋀ s'. s → s' ⟹ terminating s') ⟹ terminating s"
```

I would like to prove that if a node s is not terminating then there exists an infinite chain of the form s0 → s1 → s2 → .... Something among the lines of:

```
 lemma "¬ terminating (c,s) ⟹ 
       ∃ cfs. (cfs 0 = (c,s) ∧ (∀ n. (cfs n) → (cfs (n+1))))"
```

How can I prove this in Isabelle?

**Edit**

The final goal is to prove the following goal:

```
lemma "(∀s t. (c, s) ⇒ t = (c', s) ⇒ t) ⟹
       terminating (c, s) = terminating (c', s) "
```

where ⇒ is the big step semantics of the GCL. Perhaps another method is needed to prove this theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using the choice operator, you can easily construct a witness using `SOME`, for instance:

```
primrec infinite_trace :: ‹'s ⇒ nat ⇒ 's› where 
  ‹infinite_trace c0 0 = c0›
| ‹infinite_trace c0 (Suc n) =
    (SOME c. infinite_trace c0 n → c ∧ ¬ terminating c)›
```

(I was not sure about the types of your `s` and `(c,s)` values—so I just used `'s` for that.)

Obviously, the witness construction would fail if at some point `SOME` cannot pick a value satisfying the constraint. So, one still has to prove that the non-termination indeed propagates (as is quite obvious from the definition):

```
lemma terminating_suc:
  assumes ‹¬ terminating c›
  obtains c' where ‹c → c'› ‹¬ terminating c'›
  using assms terminating.intros by blast

lemma nontermination_implies_infinite_trace:
  assumes ‹¬ terminating c0›
  shows  ‹¬ terminating (infinite_trace c0 n) 
    ∧ infinite_trace c0 n → infinite_trace c0 (Suc n)›
  by (induct n,
     (simp, metis (mono_tags, lifting) terminating_suc assms exE_some)+)
```

Proving your existential quantification using `infinite_trace (c,s)` as a witness is straight-forward.

Comment: thank you! i have not seen the choice operator before, why do you think I might be uncomfortable using it? is the axiom of choice the problem here?

Comment: Some people try to use Choice as rarely as possible for somewhat philosophical reasons. If you ask me, it's extremely practical in order to formulate constructions like the above one in Isabelle/HOL. ;)